# How to choose a category in food ordering app which opens that particular section?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I'm making a food ordering application on java using Android Studio IDE. I have designed my application in a way that it has a section called categories in which I have implemented a recyclerView to show the different categories.
I have also figured out to open a fragment with the specific item image and name on which the user has clicked. Now comes the main problem.

I want to display a recyclerView whenever any of the category is opened and that recyclerView should show the data of that specific category. Means, if user is entering into Pizza category so that recyclerView should show him all the pizzas that I have listed on my firebase database. And when the user click on Burger category, that recyclerView should show all the burgers there.

Please help me in this, as I have taken this project and now I'm stucked with this situation.

I'm attaching some images below to help understanding easily.

[The image showing the categories.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQPxo.png)

[The image showing the fragment opening after clicked on Pizza category.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgQcp.png)

[The image showing the code of RecyclerView.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SchzY.png)

If anything else is required related to the code, I will be happy to share it.

I have tried using switch case but then I figured out that I can not update the code each time a new category is added to add a new case for each category. Also, I got failed while implementing that too!

Comment: So you need code or a database schema that can help you achieve what you want?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I need code.